# Filtering Github issues created from task list

Tags: github, github-issues

Is there a way to filter(out) issues in issue search that are `tracked` by some other issue in Github?

Context:

We are using Github feature called `Break issues into actionable tasks` as listed [here](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-06-23-whats-new-with-github-issues/)

This feature allows creating a new issue per task that you identify. Resulting in the creation of many issues that are not really issues in classical terms but are development tasks.

There are a few scenarios where we may want to exclude these issues. One of them is the triage process. During triage, we want to look at only original issues and without having to wade through numerous dev task issues.

Yes, we can create a label and (painstakingly) apply that label to each sub-issue and then filter out that label in the issue search. This is very error-prone too.

I was wondering if github provides a filter like `tracked:true` to isolate these issues. I am hopeful as github displays this linkage on sub-issue detail page as shown below:

[image]